# How to set the code annotation size in Quarto HTML/RevealJS documents?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

Creating a RevealJS / HTML document in Quarto and making use of the [code annotation](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/code-annotation.html) feature. However, the resulting annotation (numbered circles and the accompanying text) is larger than I'd like. How can I change it?
I've been trying to edit SCSS, for example

```
.code-annotation-container-grid dd {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

will get the text of the annotations smaller but the numbers remain large. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this? If not, what can I edit to set the annotation row size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the followings,

```css
.reveal dl.code-annotation-container-grid {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.reveal dl.code-annotation-container-grid dt {
  margin-top: 0.4rem;
}
```